# How to target IE9 with new HTML5 Boilerplate?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, html5boilerplate, conditional-comments

I am trying to target a class for IE. However, since the boilerplate template has changed this no longer works..

```
.myclass {
 //do something
}


.ie7 .myclass {
 ///do something

 }
```

This is what's in the new header of the boilerplate template.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We do not recommend you target IE9 as it has all the marking of a modern browser, which is why we do not have IE9 specific conditional class. If you still would like to, you can use:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie10" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Note that [IE10 will not recognize conditional comments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx).

Comment: Glad I found this. box-shadow is bugged in IE9 and IE10. This will come in handy for fixing the issue in IE9. IE10 unfortunately will have to remain a problem I guess. :(

Comment: I must say that if this workaround is to be used, than it would be more correct to include lt-ie10 class into all conditional comments, not only in the IE 9 one, so that selector .lt-ie10 would work for *all* IE's prior to 10 :)

Comment: I had to target IE9 due to wrong calculcation of padding inside a 'header' when the `font-size` inside the header was in em's

Comment: Would not IE10 and some other browser missing `<html>` tag?

Comment: There is one special exception where even conditional comments don't help. When your page is opened in an iframe where the host has quirks mode on. Usually if it goes the other way around IE simulates quirks mode for the iframe but if the host is in quirks the iframe is also rendered in quirks (as IE cannot render one webpage with two engines at once). In this case conditional comment's don't work and you have to fall back on JS hacks to get the stuff looking good with polyfills and shivs.

Answer (score 0):

Yak Boilerplate! Anyway:

```
.lt-ie9.lt-ie8 .myclass {}
```

should do what you want.

**EDIT**

Sorry misread your question since you put IE7 in example. If you want to IE9 you can just do:

```
.myclass {}
```

Comment: Correct! However, that will only only target IE7. "lt" means less then. so .lt-ie9 will target IE8. I need to target IE9 as well..so changing it to .lt-ie10 doesn't work...Any ideas?

Comment: well I need to target IE for: "color: transparent;" as far as I know it's not supported.