# How to stop all scripts from loading for IE 9 and less users

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I added a this code to the header to redirect IE user using IE 10 or less

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/outdated_browser"><style> body { display:none; } </style><![endif]-->
```

The problem is that my page is loading some scripts causing internet explorer to crash, my question is, is there any way to stop all the scripts from loading for those users and automatically redirect them to the update you browser page?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to target IE9 with new HTML5 Boilerplate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233468/how-to-target-ie9-with-new-html5-boilerplate)

Comment: try linking to different stylesheets - such as <!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]--> instead of putting it in the html

Comment: Try fixing your scripts. Not everyone can update their browser, and it is unlikely that someone will be so deperate to visit your page that they will upgrade, even if they can.

Answer (score 1):

That will cover the effect you want by redirecting them before the scripts run, but I'm with RobG on the fact that those scripts should be prioritized and fixed. This should be put ahead of any of the scripts you load in the page so that the redirect is prioritized.

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "YOUR LINK HERE";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```