# Sorting child elements within a div A-Z vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[This is how it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuTXv.jpg)

So currently I have it ordered A-Z horizontally but my end game is to have it vertically.

I'll explain how the code currently works.

So it's a collection of `a` tags contained within a `div` which has a fixed width of 700px and the contents are floated left. There is a `onclick` function enabled on the parent link which when clicked runs the following:

```
onclick="
        if($('#random-word01').css('display') != 'block'){ 
           closeOpennedIndustry()
        }; 
        $( '#random-word1' ).slideToggle(200); 
        $( '#toggleRandomWord h3.h3-random-word' ).toggle()"
```

Which enables the dropdown.

I figured the best way to change this would be to make the divs in a unordered list and float them all left instead of horizontally. However, I ran into issues with the positioning of the dropdown.

What would be the best way to achieve having the links A-Z with the dropdown working A-Z and in the correct place.

Comment: You have to post relevant code in question. BTW, providing a jsFiddle would motive people to try to help you

Comment: without the relevant code, it is imposible to answer precisely but from what I can see, CSS column display might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to tell without knowing how the markup is being generated (e.g. coming from a CMS like WordPress? Static HTML?).

CSS Columns can help you get the list to run vertically instead of horizontally (and degrade gracefully back to horizontal). Use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect for columns, and/or use [IE Conditional Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233468/how-to-target-ie9-with-new-html5-boilerplate) to write styles for both cases.

If you want exact cross-browser compatibility, you can also wrap columns in ULs and float them with clearfixes.

1. In PHP/WordPress, counter the number of links in the list (say 40), the number of columns you want (say six), and divide/mod to know how many in each (six columns of six and one of four). Output  tags around that many elements and float them left.
2. You can do the same with JS, but you’ll be subject to FOUC (flash of unstyled content) and possibly a performance problem.

Hope any of that helps! If it’s not relevant, apologies—we didn’t get much from your question to work with.

Good luck!